# Rails 3. Decide on save if the object should be saved or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, save

iam just asking myself, whats the best solution for my problem.

Here are my models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices, :class_name => "ProductPrice"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
end

class ProductPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

The controller

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])

  @product.save
  ...
end
```

What i want to do is to prevent all ProductPrices from being saved when `product_price.value == nil` or `product_price.value == 0.0`

1. `before_save` hook in ProductPrice. `return false` **will rollback** the whole transaction, thats not what i want to do. i just want to "kick" all prices with `value == 0 or value == nil`
2. first kick all price_params from `params[...]` and than call `Product.new(params[:product])` seems not to be the rails way eighter...
3. after `Product.new(params[:product])` iterate over all prices and delete them from the array. but the logic should be in my models right? i just dont want to repeat myself on every controller that creates new prices...

can someone tell me the best solution for that? whats the rails way?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want it called a validation hook, something like this:

```
class ProductPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  validates :value, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0.0 }
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html for other ways you may want to do this with finer control.

To avoid adding these invalid prices in the first place, you can remove them from the nested attributes hash like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.clean_attributes!(product_params)
    product_prices = product_params['prices'] || []
    product_prices.reject!{|price| price['value'].to_f == 0 rescue true }
  end
end

Product.clean_attributes!(params[:product])
Product.new(params[:product])
```

Comment: but this would rollback the transaction and raise some errors in the views. thats not what i want. if i execute product.save then i want that product being saved and all prices > 0 too! without errors and rollbacks.

Comment: If so, you can remove those product_prices from the nested attributes hash before passing to save - see updated.

Comment: oh well, thats a nice idea. the problem with this solution is, that it will not cover this situation somewere in other controllers: `price.value = 0; price.save`. this should destroy the object. is that possible somehow?

Comment: is this something that may occur on items that are already saved in the database, meaning the record should be destroyed?  Or is this only a concern for new records?

Comment: yes, already saved object should get destroyed and new objects should never be saved on that condition.

Comment: The simplest way to do this would be to always check validity before saving.  If it's invalid, you can call destroy on it then. You can make a helper method to wrap all of this in one call. Once you enter the `save` callback hierarchy, you would need to rely on a hack to do what you want. Such a hack would probably qualify as 'evil' and not recommended because of the internals it would need to reach and be dependent upon.

Comment: oh well, it works! calling `destroy` on `before_validation` in `class ProductPrice`. is it save for create and update? will the reference in `@product.prices` get removed quickly?